# Defaultly focusing last column when applying alwaysEditing=true attribute in the Dojo Datagrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I have number of columns to be in always edit mode so i am applying **alwaysEditing=true** for No of Columns the Pointer is always focusing the last column even if i select any other column in the Grid. 
I need a solution that whenever i click any column the Pointer should focus on the selected instead of last column in the Grid.

Comment: I have made a patch for this(in the source code). I can give it you at Monday.

Comment: Thanks GuyT am awaiting for you reply.

Comment: Not sure if it was this patch: `file: /dojox/grid/DataGrid.js
remove following code: if(_4c3){this.grid.updateRow(r);}` Are you able to try it(this is in the compressed version)?